# I have "User" class and 2 classes "Student" and "Teacher" inherit from it, but when I run the spring boot app it creates only "User" table

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, inheritance, spring-data-jpa

I'am using jakarta and when I run the app the "Student" and "Teacher" tables didn't created and only the "User" table is created. What could be the problem ?

### User class

```js
import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;


    public User(String first_name, String last_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public User() {}
}
```

### Student class

```js
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;


@Entity
public class Student extends User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = jakarta.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students")
@JoinTable(
        name = "student_module",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "module_id"))
private Set<Module> modules;

    private double moyenneGenerale;


    public Student(String first_name, String last_name) {
        super(first_name, last_name);
    }

    public Student() {
    }
}
```

### Module class:

```js
import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Module implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Subject> subjects;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "modules")
    private Set<Student> students;


    public Module(Set<Subject> subjects) {

    }

    public Module() {}


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Set<Subject> getSubjects() {
        return subjects;
    }

    public void setSubjects(Set<Subject> subjects) {
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }

    public void calculMoyenne() {

    }
}
```

### Subject class:

```js
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Subject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int coefficient;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "module_id")
    private Module module;


    public Subject(String name, int coefficient, Module module) {
        this.name = name;
        this.coefficient = coefficient;
        this.module = module;
    }

    public Subject() {}


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getCoefficient() {
        return coefficient;
    }

    public void setCoefficient(int coefficient) {
        this.coefficient = coefficient;
    }

}
```

> ERROR 7576 --- [           main]
> j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA
> EntityManagerFactory: Collection
> 'com.example.grademanagement_hamzarami.models.Student.modules' is
> 'mappedBy' a property named 'student' which does not exist in the
> target entity 'com.example.grademanagement_hamzarami.models.Module'

> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
> path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
> Collection
> 'com.example.grademanagement_hamzarami.models.Student.modules' is
> 'mappedBy' a property named 'student' which does not exist in the
> target entity 'com.example.grademanagement_hamzarami.models.Module'

Comment: Have you read the error message? `'com.example.grademanagement_hamzarami.models.Student.modules' is 'mappedBy' a property named 'student' which does not exist in the target entity 'com.example.grademanagement_hamzarami.models.Module'`

Comment: "you are using jakarta"..but (in Student): `import javax.persistence..` this is "contradictory" (to what i imagine under "using jakarta")

Comment: @xerx593 I thought i could use both libraries in the same time but even I remove javax and use jakarta instead in all classes the error still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your Module @Entity lacks a student field so your module table lacks this column.

However, I suspect that your have a model problem.

The relationship between Student and Module is ManyToMany (aka associative), ie a Student can enrole in many Modules and a Module can be presented to many Students.

[This](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many) almost the same model if you substitute Course of Module.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I really appreciate it, but even after I modify the relationships the problem still the same. I've added "Module" and "Subject" classes for more details.

Comment: You have not used everything required from https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many

Comment: I've added "JoinTable" and I made some changes but it didn't works

Answer (score 0):

Modify Student entity like this:

```
@JsonManagedReference
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students")
private List<Module> modules;
```

And also you should use Set instead of List for all the relations.

EDIT: Each entity must have getters and setters for each and every field.

Comment: I've added "mappedBy = "students" and used Set instead of List but the error still the same